# Why webpack imports all files in subdirectory instead of the right

Tags: reactjs, webpack, import, require

I have React app which render 300 pages. They are divided into 4 groups. There are common settings, custom settings for each group and settings for each page in .json files. I don't want to load all the settings for all pages, but only those needed for a particular page. I try use require to import necessary file:

```
const getThemeConfig = (theme) => {
  const filePath = `./themes/${theme}/config.json`;
  return require(`${filePath}`)
};
const themeConfig = getThemeConfig(currentTheme);
```

this file is imported, but at the same time the application tries to upload absolutely all .json files in ./themes directory. IDK how to fix it.

Comment: I think i find a solution using require.context which have an option to includeSubdirs

Comment: Yes, you can require the json and use it.